# Cufon dynamically resize, is it possible?

Tags: jquery-plugins, cufon

I've got a jQuery Roundabout loaded, aswell as Cufon for a custom font. When another box is clicked that box then resizes baded on "em's" or "%"'s so what I'd like to know is...

When a user clicks the next box, can I get the Cufon (Styled to H2) to resize based on EM's or is it a big no, no?

Not sure how to represent this as an example, as I am working locally on a Joomla site. Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call Cufon.replace("h2") again after you've resized the H2 in your CSS.

Comment: I've got the Cufon loaded in the head. Already, So you're saying load it after - Put it at the end of the body?

Comment: Call Cufon.replace in the head when you first display your H2 elements as you are already. Then, when the resize happens on box click, call Cufon.replace() again and it will regenerate the images with the new font-size.